# valet share unsecured 301 redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-valet, roots-sage

I'm using [roots.io](http://roots.io)'s Bedrock and Sage and Laravel's Valet share (unsecured), and I just cannot get it to work on ONE site.

The site works locally on abcd.test/ and all my other sites work both locally and with Valet share (new installations), but this is an older site that I have migrated across to Bedrock/Sage and Valet.

Somehow, when I valet share, the ngrok.io domain keeps redirecting to my .test/ domain on the home page, which means I get a "301 Moved Permanently" redirect in Terminal, and trying to access the site remotely redirects to example.test/ instead of the ngrok.io domain. Note, accessing the ngrok URL with a subpage DOES work, but all of the assets are still served from the .test/ domain.

**Recap:**

- abcd.ngrok.io -> redirects to abcd.test/
- abcd.ngrok.io/about-us -> works (stays as abcd.ngrok.io/about-us)
     but all assets are served from abcd.test/ (therefore breaking
     externally)
- abcd.ngrok.io/wp-admin -> redirects to abcd.test/wp-admin

Also note, I am using a .env file to create my WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL, as per the Bedrock specifications.

I am stumped!